# This spammer should be deleted

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, spam

This user: https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/108323/baby-doll has posted a two spam answers. The spam answers are probably the only contribution they will ever make. I think this user should be deleted. If the user was deleted because of this question, please add [status-completed](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/status-completed),

Comment: As a relatively new user of the site, please learn what is the best way to do things rather than telling the old hands what to do. Before I could see your post here, the user had been reported for spam and action taken.

Comment: @Willeke Why did you decline if that user DID get deleted

Comment: Because the user was handled before your post had been seen. (I do not want to encourage you to post this kind of posts, flagging as spam if you have the option, is the way to go.)

Comment: @Willeke Should I or you delete this question?

Comment: @Asadefa nah, leave the Q here - it might help other users who see it to realise they can just flag users, rather than ask a whole Question. Thanks!

Comment: I agree with @MarkMayo

Answer (score 4):

Moderators are notified when a sustained flag is generated. There's no need to post to remove a given spam user. Mods will see it and take action accordingly. Just red-flag the post.

Comment: When the system records a user or even an IP area with too many spam reports they put the user or the whole area under extra control, banning those which are proved to be spamming.